# How can I limit my heading by the quantity of two lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have a grid of posts width the content like this:

```
<img src="/" alt="Logo">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Description</p>
<div>Date</div>
```

And if my post's heading has more than two lines, I would like to clip it and in the end of the second line print ellipsis.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your required [level of support](https://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp) the CSS only `line-clamp` approach may be suitable.

If not, then there is a small JS library available to do this called [Succinct](https://github.com/micjamking/Succinct). There is a demo [here](http://mikeking.io/succinct/) - just scroll down when the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `display:-webkit-box` along with `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;`, it will avoid displaying more than 2 lines in your heading.

**Note:**

Note that it has some cross-browser issues but it's something you can go with, at the moment.

**CSS:**

```
#myHeading {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
#myHeading {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  
  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<img src="/" alt="Logo">
<h3 id="myHeading">Heading id d yz eee,zbez, zeze e ee e, e,z e, e,zaezjhezeze zaez ezae e zazejzaee je zaje zaj ezae ze ejeazezaje ej j ezaje zaej azej ejjzejze j e zaeje eze zjeezejzadsdofdspflf dsufofod fdofds fdf fo dfofo udfodsfdHeading</h3>
<p>Description</p>
<div>Date</div>
```

Comment: @AlexanderRodin Yes, that's what I said. :(